# Why does Go's package flag use pointers?

Tags: pointers, go

Consider the following code from [`gopl.io/ch2/echo4`](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch2/echo4/main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var n = flag.Bool("n", false, "omit trailing newline")
var sep = flag.String("s", " ", "separator")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Print(strings.Join(flag.Args(), *sep))
    if !*n {
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

I'm interested why the variables `n` and `sep` are **pointers** to the flag variables, rather than normal variable type.

Comment: If it would not be a pointer than flag.Parse could not modify their value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because they need to be assigned value after they are created. The order of actions is:

1. Create variable `var n = flag.Bool("n", false, "omit trailing newline")` The value is false now.
2. Assign value with `flag.Parse()`. Variable is now assigned value passed as command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code [here](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.regabi/src/flag/flag.go#1033), you'll see that there's an exported variable called `CommandLine`, which is a pointer to a `FlagSet`. This is where the magic happens. When you import that library, it's instantiated. When you invoke the exported functions, for example, `flag.Bool()`, that function, in turn, calls the *method* `Bool()`, which has a pointer receiver to...`FlagSet`. It will create a new `bool` to store your flag's value, invoke `BoolVar()` to store a pointer to the newly created `bool` variable within the `FlagSet` data structure (you'll need to trace `BoolVar` to see how this is accomplished), and returns the very same pointer to you so you can later get the **current** value (which could be the default value or an entirely new value as a result of the call to`Parse()`)

```
// CommandLine is the default set of command-line flags, parsed from os.Args.
// The top-level functions such as BoolVar, Arg, and so on are wrappers for the
// methods of CommandLine.
var CommandLine = NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], ExitOnError)
```

```
// NewFlagSet returns a new, empty flag set with the specified name and
// error handling property. If the name is not empty, it will be printed
// in the default usage message and in error messages.
func NewFlagSet(name string, errorHandling ErrorHandling) *FlagSet {
    f := &FlagSet{
        name:          name,
        errorHandling: errorHandling,
    }
    f.Usage = f.defaultUsage
    return f
}
```

```
// A FlagSet represents a set of defined flags. The zero value of a FlagSet
// has no name and has ContinueOnError error handling.
//
// Flag names must be unique within a FlagSet. An attempt to define a flag whose
// name is already in use will cause a panic.
type FlagSet struct {
    // Usage is the function called when an error occurs while parsing flags.
    // The field is a function (not a method) that may be changed to point to
    // a custom error handler. What happens after Usage is called depends
    // on the ErrorHandling setting; for the command line, this defaults
    // to ExitOnError, which exits the program after calling Usage.
    Usage func()
    name          string
    parsed        bool
    actual        map[string]*Flag
    formal        map[string]*Flag
    args          []string // arguments after flags
    errorHandling ErrorHandling
    output        io.Writer // nil means stderr; use Output() accessor
}
```

```
// Bool defines a bool flag with specified name, default value, and usage string.
// The return value is the address of a bool variable that stores the value of the flag.
func (f *FlagSet) Bool(name string, value bool, usage string) *bool {
    p := new(bool)
    f.BoolVar(p, name, value, usage)
    return p
}

// Bool defines a bool flag with specified name, default value, and usage string.
// The return value is the address of a bool variable that stores the value of the flag.
func Bool(name string, value bool, usage string) *bool {
    return CommandLine.Bool(name, value, usage)
}
```

Going back to your question:

> why the variables n and sep are pointers to the flag variables, rather than normal variable type.

It's because `Parse()` can manipulate the original variables and your new variables `n` and `sep` would have only captured a copy of the original **values**. By using the pointer, you and the `FlagSet` are looking at exact the same variables.